# Is there a way in Python to search directories, subdirectories and files recursively without using os.walk, glob, or fnmatch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, directory

I know that using these modules makes life a lot easier but as I learn Python, I want to be able to solidify the foundation and then go onto the shortcuts. That way, when presented with the bigger issue, I can analyze and solve it.

I want to be able to return the number of total folders and files in 1 directory such as directory F:\

I have come up with:

```
import os

def fcount(path):
  count = 0
  for f in os.listdir(path):
    file = os.path.join(path, f)
    if os.path.isdir(file):
      file_count = fcount(file)
      count += file_count + 1

  for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
      count += 1
  return count

path = 'F:\\'
print(fcount(path))
```

This is the final answer. This gives you the total number of subdirectories and files within the specified directory.

Comment: I'd look at the [`os.walk()` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/os.py#l298) and go from there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have made some edits and changes. Does that clarify what I am getting at?

Comment: So what are you struggling with here? What problem did you encounter that we need to explain?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to be able to count all the files within the directory F:\ including subfolders.
So for example, I have a total of 50 folders in my directory. But within those folders, there are more folders and/or files inside them. I want to be able to count all the files and folders and return the number of items total.

Comment: Right, it wasn't clear that you wanted to *recurse* into subdirectories. What did you try to make that work? Do you know about recursion or, alternatively using a stack or queue? Did you look at the `os.walk()` source code to see how it does this?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Still entry level recursion and have read a little bit on stacking. Nothing about queues yet though. Essentially just looked at `os.walk()` and tried dissecting it into what I included in the code above. But now I need to go a level deeper. And since I'm still unsure of how certain things work in full, it's getting confusing where I need to add my next steps. Would that mean using an additional loop? If so, would it go within what I currently have under the if? But I'm still stuck on how it would be written.

Comment: For every directory, just call `fcount()` again with the path to that directory. Add up the result to your current count. Done!

Comment: You'll need to not count directories of course. Just add to 1 to count when a file is *not* a directory. For directories, recurse as you do now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113267/discussion-between-adhamncheese-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Look at `scandir` at https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/blob/master/scandir.py#L99 for an example how to do it right. While on the subject, is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the number of all files under a directory (recursively) without using `os.walk` or something that uses the same thing.

This information requires this job and you cannot do it another way. Obviously that there are other libraries that are doing a similar job with some variations but the point is that's the mainly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to do just as os.walk would do. It's manual recursion.

```
import os

def fcount(path):
    count = 0
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        file = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            file_count = fcount(file)
            count += file_count + 1

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
        count += 1
    return count

path = 'F:\\'
print(fcount(path))
```

Note: Initially in OP, there was no second loop.